# Swapping 1 with 0 and 0 with 1 in a Pythonic way

Tags: python

In some part of my Python program I have a val variable that can be 1 or 0. If it's 1 I must change to 0, if it's 0 I must change to 1.

How do you do it in a Pythonic way?

```
if val == 1:
    val = 0
elif val == 0:
    val = 1
```

it's too long!

I did:

```
swap = {0: 1, 1:0}
```

So I can use it:

```
swap[val]
```

Other ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `True`/`False` instead of `1`/`0` in your case?

Comment: The most Pythonic way to do this would take into account the meaning of the variable.  Is it numeric?  Boolean (i.e. True/False)?  Does it have some semantic meaning that isn't obvious here?  The mere fact that you want to toggle it implies that it has some meaning... what is it?

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is "toggle".

Comment: I ended up using your `swap` solution because when I come back to this in years, it will immediately make sense to me. Also, it is extensible and customizable, in case I eventually need to work with more/different numbers.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

This isn't pythonic, but it is language neutral. Often `val = 1 - val` is simplest.

Comment: That is clever, but it requires the person reading your code to think (probably), which may force you to have add a comment.  I like the ternary better eg. val = 0 if val else 1 because it says exactly what it does.

Comment: Another way of saying the same thing: var=((var+1)&1).

Comment: I guess I would just create a method called `bit_flip` and use the code in this answer. Once the name is there, it should be pretty easy to pick up what it does.

Comment: `val = 1 - val` in no way communicates `val` is always either `1` or `0` and that it is supposed to *swap/flip* these values. `marked = not marked` communicates both.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastien: The original poster didn't say why, but seemed to want a number and not a boolean so you'd have to do `int(not val)` to get _exactly_ the same behaviour. I think that this was discussed on the comments to one of the other answers.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: `True == 1` and `False == 0` in Python. Arithmetic is the same; though [you might see the difference if you call `str(val)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779286/swapping-1-with-0-and-0-with-1-in-a-pythonic-way#comment1665509_1779305). You don't need the *exact* `int` in many cases.

Answer (score 59):

The shortest approach is using the bitwise operator XOR.

If you want `val` to be reassigned:

```
val ^= 1
```

If you do not want `val` to be reassigned:

```
val ^ 1
```

Comment: I like this answer because it provides the opportunity to do the swap dynamically, using "`^ 1`" or "`^ 0`", with the latter leading to no swap.

Answer (score 33):

Since `True == 1` and `False == 0` in python,

you could just use `var = not var`

It will just swap it.

Comment: This seems an implementation detail and can't rely on it.

Comment: but `int(not 1) == 0` and `int(not 0) == 1` because `int(True) == 1` and `int(False) == 0`. and this one is likely not an implementation detail.

Comment: bool is a subclass of int, and Alex Martelli uses `sum([list of booleans]` to count the number of True's, so I think it must be safe.

Comment: The fact that 0 evalutes to false, and 1 to true in a boolean context are both guaranteed in python: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Comment: seems like telling `var = not var` is like `parsing html with regex` in SO? I can't believe that!

Comment: It's safe (and just fine!) if all you ever do with `var` is arithmetic (nothing to do with "parsing html with regex", which is just silly!-), but if you ever do a `str(var)` (including an intrinsic one e.g. in `print`), bool behaves differently (as a subclass, it overrides `__str__`). Not enough info in the question to make sure there's no such stringification, so `1 - var` as in the selected answer is safer.

Comment: It's safe but not expressive as prose, which is why i would suggest using the ternary (see my answer).

Comment: Coming from a background of digital/boolean logic, this approach seems the most clear, concise and readable.

Comment: To address the concern noted by @AlexMartelli, I have submitted a derived [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38361873/832230) that additionally uses `int`.

Answer (score 19):

Just another possibility:

```
i = (1, 0)[i]
```

This works well as long as `i` is positive, as [dbr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745/) pointed out in the comments it doesn't work for `i < 0`.

Are you sure you don't want to use `False` and `True`? It sounds almost like it.

Comment: It wont error if `i` is `-1` or `-2`, and would act strangely. `{0: 1, 1:0}[i]` would error however

Comment: @dbr thanks. I wanted to include this in the answer, but then I saw that the OP had already found this answer. I'm sticking with the one I have because it's really compact.

Answer (score 10):

To expand upon the [answer by "YOU"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1779305/832230), use:

```
int(not(val))
```

Examples:

```
>>> val = 0
>>> int(not(val))
1

>>> val = 1
>>> int(not(val))
0
```

Note that this answer is only meant to be descriptive, not prescriptive.

Answer (score 8):

In your case I recommend the ternary:

```
val = 0 if val else 1
```

If you had 2 variables to swap you could say:

```
(a, b) = (b, a)
```

Comment: OP doesn't have two values to swap. he has a single value that he wants to change

Answer (score 6):

I have swapped 0s and 1s in a list.

Here's my list:

```py
list1 = [1,0,0,1,0]

list1 = [i^1 for i in list1] 
#xor each element is the list

print(list1)
```

So the outcome is: [0,1,1,0,1]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple way:

```
val = val + 1 - val * 2
```

For Example:

If val is 0

```
0+1-0*2=1
```

If val is 1

```
1+1-1*2=0
```

Comment: you could make it simpler : val = 1 - val

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be short:

```
f = lambda val: 0 if val else 1
```

Then:

```
>>> f(0)
1
>>> f(1)
0
```

Answer (score 3):

The most pythonic way would probably be

```
int(not val)
```

But a shorter way would be

```
-~-val
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
val = (not val) * 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way:

```
val = ~val + 2
```

Answer (score 1):

(0,1)[not val]
flips the val from 0 to 1 and vice versa.

Comment: [`not val`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1779305/4279) *by itself* flips the val from `0` to `1`. Note: `False == 0` and `1 == True` in Python.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing all these simpler answers i thought of adding an abstract one , it's Pythonic though :

```
val = set(range(0,2)).symmetric_difference(set(range(0 + val, val + 1))).pop()
```

All we do is return the difference of 2 sets namely **[0, 1]** and **[val]** where **val** is either 0 or 1.

we use [symmetric_difference()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/symmetric_difference) to create the set **[0, 1] - [val]** and [pop()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/pop) to assign that value to variable **val**.

Comment: How is this Pythonic? From the Zen of Python: "readability counts"

Comment: young me discovered something new , decided to write about it

Answer (score 0):

Function with mutable argument. Calling the `swaper()` will return different value every time.

```py
def swaper(x=[1]):
    x[0] ^= 1
    return x[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your way works well!

What about:

```
val = abs(val - 1)
```

short and simple!

Comment: or `val = 1 - val`

Answer (score 0):

use np.where

ex.

```
np.where(np.array(val)==0,1,0)
```

this gives 1 where val is 0 and gives 0 where val is anything else, in your case 1

EDIT: val has to be array

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an array and it is in numpy you can use

```
>> y = np.array([1,0,1,1])
>> y^1
[0,1,0,0]
```