# Change a value from 0->1 or 1->0 with only mathematic operations

Tags: javascript, operators, boolean-operations

I have a variable on javascrit, initialized at 0. What I'd like to do is this :

- if the value is 0, change it to 1;
- if the value is 1, change it to 0;

and I'll avoid conditional statement (like if/else) to check what the value is.

I think I just do it with some matematic operation; I thought to a NOT operation, but I don't know how to do that operation without

Comment: **Why** do you want to avoid if/else? Any reason?

Comment: There aren't a specific reason. Just I think there is a way more quick to change a value from 0->1 or 1->0, without first check and than set the value...

Comment: By "quick" do you mean performance of the code? If so, you're looking at the wrong end: your micro-optimizing and you're *probably* doing it at the wrong side of the code. Make sure that you **measure** before you try to optimize.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779286/swapping-1-with-0-and-0-with-1-in-a-pythonic-way

Comment: @Joachim Sauer : you solution looks brillant. You don't think apply a SUM (1-x) is faster than check a variable, than edit the value?

Comment: @markzzz: I *do* have an *intuition*, but I've seen enough "optimizations" that are actually worse than the original code to know that doing optimizations by intuition is a **terribly bad idea**. VMs (and most JS these days is executed by a virtual machine) have a tendency to optimize common code blocks very well. So doing something the "naive" way may actually turn out to *run faster* than the "optimized" code. Again: **measure**, *then* optimize, *then measure again!*

Comment: ok! ;) In fact I need to work on array with lenght 4, so the time to execute the code will be small in any case. I need this solution for a fast implementation of the code, and with your intuition, changing those values is a good way for me :) Thanks you

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
x = 1-x;
```

Answer (score 10):

Short XOR syntax:

```
x ^= 1
```

Swaps 0 to 1 and 1 to 0.

Comment: `x ^= 0` returns 0

Comment: @mirik its always `x ^= 1` - x is switching between 0 and 1

Answer (score 4):

you can use xor operator:

```
x = x XOR 1;
```

Comment: Note that the syntax would use `^`, not `XOR`. So `x = x ^ 1;`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 2):

If the variable is let's say i

i = 1 - i, should do the trick

if i = 0,   1 - 0 = 1 than i = 1

if i = 1,   1 - 1 = 0 than i = 0

Answer (score 2):

Here is another notation, it also changes true, false to 1, 0.

```
x = +x;
```

If you want to switch the value

```
x = +!x;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let flip = (...array)=> {

  let res = []

for(let each of array){
 res.push([1,0][each])
 }

console.log(res)
 }

flip(0,1,1,1,0,0,1)
```