# Python Classes, how to flip between players

Tags: python

I have a list of players stored and I would like to flip between them. For example first, I ask player1 for input , and once he done I will ask player2 for input and after ask player3 , and ask player 1 again. and so on so forth.

It doesn't have to be only 3 player , it can be more or less than that

code:

```
fn = []
player_name = input("Enter player " + str(i+1) + " name: ")
fn.append(player_name)
print("1. Attack")
print("2. Charge")
print("3. Shield")
input(fn + " what would you like to do?  ")
print(str(minion.name) + " HP " + str(minion.hp))
uska = input(fn + " who would you like to attack? ")
```

so all the players are stored in "fn" but I can't concatenate it to the str. If I do fn[0] it only brings first name but I want it to flip between them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swapping 1 with 0 and 0 with 1 in a Pythonic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779286/swapping-1-with-0-and-0-with-1-in-a-pythonic-way)

Comment: @MikeScotty thank you, however, lets say I have 7 players not 2. how is that works then?

Comment: and players MUST be stored in a list

Comment: You could put all your players in a list and then [rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-rotate-a-list-in-python) that list, or use a [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) object (also mentioned in the linked question)

Comment: Your original questions asked how to toggle between player1 and player2, please do not change your question fundamentalliy, as it makes it hard or impossible to answer it or to link to matching duplicates.

Comment: I am sorry, I will change it now.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight-forward way to keep looping over a list of object indeterminately is to use a while-loop:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def greeting(self):
        return f"Hello, may name is {self.name}"

def game_loop(players):
    while True:
        for player in players:
            print(player.greeting())

players = [Player('Frank'), Player("Anna"), Player("Juan")]

game_loop(players)
```

Of course, the above will give you an infinite loop. So you are going to have to take care of breaking out of your loop, note, only a break directly within the `while` loop body, not inside the for-loop, will break the infinite loop.

An alternative which may make things easier to handle is to use `itertools` and a for-loop:

```
import itertools
for player in itertools.cycle(players):
    print(player.greeting())
```

This may be easier to work with, because then you can just break out of the single loop. But this is also an infinite loop, because `cycle` returns an infinite iterator.

Note, you *could* implement cycle yourself using a generator pretty-straightforwardly, [the docs even contain these implementations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) (of course, in CPython, they aren't implemented in Python, they are implemented in C):

```
def cycle(iterable):
    # cycle('ABCD') --> A B C D A B C D A B C D ...
    saved = []
    for element in iterable:
        yield element
        saved.append(element)
    while saved:
        for element in saved:
              yield element
```

Notice, it still has this `while True: for x in whatever: ...` structure... It has just been encapsulated in an iterator, a generator in fact.